# The product of a matrix and it's transpose matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Is there any way to compute the dot product of a matrix and it's transpose matrix that is faster than the normal, O(n^3) way? I have matrix of 1000 rows and 1000 columns. If I assume `n=1000`, then I need to find the product the matrix and it's transpose matrix in something around `O(n^2)` or `O(logn*n^2)` time. Is it possible?

Comment: Thi is a question for one of the computer science or math exchanges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as there are already faster algorithms for general matrix multiplication, like the [Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm), which is ~O(N^2.8)

Comment: From the linked article: *"a 2010 study found that even a single step of Strassen's algorithm is often not beneficial on current architectures, compared to a highly optimized traditional multiplication, until matrix sizes exceed 1000 or more, and even for matrix sizes of several thousand the benefit is typically marginal at best (around 10% or less)."*

Comment: `O(n^log(7)) ~ O(n^2.8)` versus naive `O(n^log(8)) == O(n^3)`